# How to calculate the total volume of multiple overlapping parallelepipeds?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

We have a number of parallelepipeds in space, having all the edges parallel to the axes. Each parallelepiped is characterized by 6 integer values, the coordinates of two of its vertices

```
(x1; y1; z1); (x2; y2; z2) with x1 < x2; y1 < y2 and z1 < z2;
```

I have to find the total volume occupied simultaneously by two or more parallelepipeds.

Comment: The question might be considered off-topic as it is about pure mathematics and not programming-related in the strictest sense; however it seems relevant. To my understanding, if all edges are parallel to the axes, the bodies must be cuboids http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid and each separate volume would be the product of the legths of the edges. Do you really mean this or can the question be rephrased?

Comment: @Codor: I think that the solids are axis-parallel cuboids, but they overlap. The question is about finding the total volume of the overlapping sub-cuboids.

Comment: What have you researched about this problem? Have you written any code? You should post in detail where you are stuck with your problem so that people can help you with it. Otherwise, this sounds like you're asking people to do your homework.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for the qualification; in this case, the total volume would be the sum of the individual volumes minus the volume of the total intersection; roughly guessing, the intersection can be calculated naively in `O(n^2)` time, where `n` is the number of cuboids.

Comment: @MOehm Okay, all of this is already included in your answer :)

Comment: @M Oehm you are right.@Erwin Bolwidt i have tried to solve this problem efficiently and i have researched about this problem last couple of hours.i think this problem can be solved by plane sweep algorithm but i can not find any efficient source to understand this algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first look at summing the volumes of all cuboids while accounting for overlapping areas only once.

You can overlay your space with a new grid that is made up of the start and end points of all cuboids. You then effectively slice all cuboids into sub-cuboids according to that grid as illustrated below (for rectangles):

[image: sub-grid forming sub-rectangles]

Fo example, the bottom right rectangle in the image is made up of six non-intersecting sub-rectangles, whose volumes you can calculate separately.

So:

- For each axis, build an array that contains the start and end points of the cuboids. Sort the array.
- Create a three-dimensional array whose lengths corresponds to the lengths of the coordinate arrays for each axis. This array holds the information whether a cuboid in the new grid is occupied or not.
- Now iterate over the cuboids and mark all sub-cuboids in the grid that make up the cuboid as occupied.
- Iterate over the marker array and sum the volumes of all marked cuboids.

When you want to get the volume of overlapping sub-cuboids, you can either build a list of cuboid intersections and work on that, or you can make the marker array an array of counts and sum only the sub-volumes whose count is at least 2.

The above method should work for arbitrary coordinate values, even floating-point numbers. If your cuboids are limited to integers in a small range, you could do without the new grid and just use the natural integer grid as "voxels".